# Alpha Particle moving through a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, acceleration

How would I find the acceleration of an alpha particle moving through a magnetic field given the force of the magnetic field, the charge, the initial velocity and the strength of the magnetic field.

Comment: [See the Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force)

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm not sure that moving Alpha particles will be deflected in a uniform magnetic field because and if the spins and the magnetic dipole moments cancel each other out. I could not find any source that talks about Lorentz force for alpha particles, did you know one? In my opinion it is not enough and not necessary that the particle has to have a charge, but it is necessary to have a magnetic dipole moment and an intrinsic spin. Following this point of view neutrons get deflected and alpha particles not.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic force on a particle is given by the Lorentz Force:

$F=q(\vec{v}\times \vec{B})$,

where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the particle and $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field

Using Newton's second law,

$m\vec{a}=q(\vec{v}\times \vec{B})$

where $m$ is the mass of the particle

This is equivalent to:

$ma=q(vBsin\theta)$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$

In general, this is what you have to do to find acceleration, given velocity and magnetic field.

But you said that you are given the magnetic force?
If that's really the case, then all you have to do is divide that force by the mass of the particle!

Comment: Take in account that the value of q has the opposite sign to the electrons value, it is approx. twice as big as for the electron because two protons are involved and the mass has to be approx. the mass of two protons and two neutrons.

Comment: Mass and charge are retarded values due to the nucleus interactions between the four particles. That is why I wrote about the approx. values.

Comment: BUT for the reason that the magnetic dipole moments and the intrinsic spins of the four particles cancel each other out I suppose that in a uniform magnetic field there is not any deflection.

Comment: The first two comments are directed to the questioner, the last to both the questioner and to PhysLab.